# How to return the longest subsequence formed by consecutive numbers in a Python list?

Tags: python

I am able to calculate the length of the longest **ascending** subsequence formed by consecutive numbers in a list, or the largest sum of any subsequence. However, I am a bit struggling to print out the longest subsequence with consecutive numbers (e.g: 8,9,10,11,12). How can I do that? Should I create an empty list and override the values every time the num value is being checked in the new_list?

Thanks in advance,
lanuit72

```
    def longest_largest_seq(list):
       
        list = [5,6,3,8,3,4,9,8,10,12,11,99,98]
    
        largest = 0
        sum = 0
        new_list = set(list) #using set to get unique value from the list
        max_count = 0
        count = 0
    
        for num in list:
            if num - 1 not in new_list:
                sum = 0
                count = 0
                while num in new_list:
                    sum += num
                    count += 1
                    num += 1
    
                    if sum > largest:
                        largest = sum
                    if count > max_count:
                        max_count = count
        return largest, max_count
    
    print(f'Largest consecutive sum and longest consecutive subsequence', longest_largest_seq(list))
```

Comment: what are you asking exactly? what do you mean by subsequence? Is it all integers less than the largest value?

Comment: "Should I create an empty list and override the values every time the num value is being checked in the new_list?" Yep, you have the right idea, to return a list at the end, you will need to keep one, usually in a variable.

Comment: @Baryon has a fair question about clarifying what property your subsequence has to follow (is it consecutive ascending numbers?)

Comment: You need to provide the property of the subsequence as if whether its ascending or descending

Comment: Thanks for asking Baryon & Adam Burke. I were asking about how to print the longest consecutive subsequence. In that example, The original list = [5,6,3,8,3,4,9,8,10,12,11,99,98]  and  the longest consecutive subsequence is 8,9,10,11,12

Comment: 8,9,10,11,12 is *not* a subsequence of that list.

Comment: Thanks Kelly Bundy. I changed it to "a subsequence formed by consecutive numbers"

Comment: Doesn't matter. Like I said, it's not a subsequence at all. So especially not a subsequence with further restrictions. 8,9,10,11 and 8,9,10,12 are subsequences, but you can't have 11,12 in a subsequence because those two numbers don't appear in that order in the original sequence.

Comment: `"longest consecutive subsequence "`

Comment: [Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)

Comment: @sahasrara62 What's the point of telling them what they already wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
import copy

seq = sorted([5,6,3,8,3,4,9,8,10,12,11,99,98])

sub_seq1 = []
sub_seq2 = []

for index, num in enumerate(seq):
    if index < len(seq) - 1:
        if num + 1 == seq[index + 1]:
            sub_seq2.append(num)
        else:
            sub_seq2.append(num)

            if len(sub_seq2) > len(sub_seq1):
                sub_seq1 = copy.deepcopy(sub_seq2)

            sub_seq2.clear()


print(sub_seq1)
```

Comment: That prints `[8, 9, 10, 11]`.

Comment: Thanks Baryon. Just like Henry's solution, this works for the sorted list. But for an unsorted list , I guess we have to use the hash map or dictionary to keep track of the numbers, right?

Comment: The new version happens to get that one correct, but if I remove the 10, it prints `[11, 12]` instead of `[3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: You could use a sorting algorithm to do the same thing I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

a_list = [5,6,3,8,3,4,9,8,10,12,11,99,98]
sorted_list = sorted(a_list)

grouped = [list(i) for i in consecutive_groups(sorted_list)]

for i in grouped:
    print(i)

print('\n', max(grouped, key=len), sep='')
```

```
[3]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[8]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[98, 99]

[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks Henry. This works for the sorted list. But for unsorted list I guess we have to use the hash map or dictionary to keep track of the numbers, right?